# Unidentified ErrorType: __array__( )

Tags: python, netcdf, contourf

I have a script below, and it was working fine yesterday, and for some reason it doesn't today. May or may not have to do with my attempt to install anaconda in my mac os x, but other scripts worked fine.

```
    import netCDF4 as nc
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from pylab import *

    f = nc.Dataset('~/data/ncep/uwnd.mon.mean.nc')
    data = f.variables['uwnd']
    lon=f.variables['lon']
    lat=f.variables['lat']
    lev=f.variables['level']
    #calculate mean for january only from 1981 (index no starts 396) to 2010 (index no ends 757)
    zonal = np.mean(data[396:757:12,:,38,39:43],axis=0)

    lon=lon[39:43]

    font = {'size'   : 9}
    plt.rc('font', **font)

    #begin plot
    clf()
    clevs=np.arange(-10.,10.,0.5)
    plt.axis([97.5, 105., 1000., 10.])
    plt.tick_params(direction='out', which='both')
    plt.xlabel('Lon (degrees)')
    plt.ylabel('Pressure (mb)')
    plt.xticks(np.arange(97.5, 105., .5),'vertical')
    plt.yticks([1000, 700, 500, 300, 100, 10])
    cs=plt.contourf(lon, lev, zonal, clevs, extend='both',cmap='seismic')
    plt.yscale('log')

    cax = fig.add_axes([0.99, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8]) #plot colorbar
    aa=fig.colorbar(cs,cax=cax,orientation='vertical')
    aa.set_label('m/s')
    plt.show()

  #end
```

and I got this error:

```
  >$ python plot-crossection-zonal-at5N-test2.py

    File "plot-crossection-zonal-at5N-test2.py", line 37, in <module>

    cs=plt.contourf(lon, lev, zonal, clevs, extend='both',cmap='seismic')

    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2712, in contourf
    ret = ax.contourf(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 5325, in contourf
    return mcontour.QuadContourSet(self, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1428, in __init__
    ContourSet.__init__(self, ax, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 874, in __init__
    self._process_args(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1441, in _process_args
    x, y, z = self._contour_args(args, kwargs)
    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1505, in _contour_args
    x, y, z = self._check_xyz(args[:3], kwargs)
    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 1535, in _check_xyz
    y = np.asarray(y, dtype=np.float64)
    File "/Users/fadzilnor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 460, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    TypeError: __array__() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

What is this error all about?

Comment: that is the classic "if day==Friday: throw an error" code... ;-)  more seriously, thanks for this, it solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the solution,
I just need to put colon,

```
    lev=f.variables['level'][:]
```

as shown below:

```
    f = nc.Dataset('~/data/ncep/uwnd.mon.mean.nc')
    data = f.variables['uwnd']
    lon=f.variables['lon']
    lat=f.variables['lat']
    lev=f.variables['level'][:] # ADDED COLON HERE

    zonal = np.mean(data[396:757:12,:,38,39:43],axis=0)#,39:43

    lon=lon[39:43]

    font = {'size'   : 9}
    plt.rc('font', **font)

    clf()
    clevs=np.arange(-10.,10.,0.5)
    plt.axis([97.5, 105., 1000., 10.])
    plt.tick_params(direction='out', which='both')
    plt.xlabel('Lon (degrees)')
    plt.ylabel('Pressure (mb)')
    plt.xticks(np.arange(97.5, 105., .5),label='vertical')
    plt.yticks([1000, 700, 500, 300, 100, 10])
    cs=plt.contourf(lon, lev, zonal, clevs, extend='both',cmap='seismic')
    plt.yscale('log')

    cax = plt.axes([0.99, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8]) #plot colorbar
    aa=plt.colorbar(cs,cax=cax,orientation='vertical')
    aa.set_label('m/s')

    plt.show()
```

Not sure the meaning of the error message, though. Happy to solve such an annoying problem.

Comment: Adding the `[:]` transforms the variable to type `numpy.ndarray`, which can then be fed into the `plt.contourf` command.  You already are doing this for the variables `lon` and `zonal` after you read them in, so that's why you only needed to do so for `level`.  I recommend reading in every variable as a `numpy.ndarray` and then manipulating them as you wish.

Comment: You can also leave `lev` as a netCDF4 object and pass the array inside the function call: `lev=f.variables['level']` and later `plt.contourf(lon, lev[:], ...)`.  (The same is true for the other netCDF4 variables.)  In case you want to retain/use the other attributes of the original object besides the array.